# KindleGen installation

Tags: command-line, software-installation, plugins

Before I came here, I searched the internet to find a solution but in vain. I cannot install the KindleGen plugin on Ubuntu 14.04 so that the Kindle comic converter can convert my jpeg images into the Kindle Paperwhite MOBI format. I downloaded KindleGen from Amazon and unarchived and decompressed it and it stood still. I don't know what actions to take. I did as the Readme text shows but "No such file or directory" shows in the terminal when I type /KindleGen/kindlegen as the instructions said.

The following are the installation instructions for Linux:

KindleGen for Linux 2.6 i386:

1. Download the KindleGen tar.gz from www.amazon.com/kindleformat/kindlegen to a folder such as Kindlegen in home directory (~/KindleGen).
2. Extract the contents of the file to '~/KindleGen'. Open the terminal, move to folder containing the downloaded file using command "cd ~/KindleGen" and then use command "tar xvfz kindlegen_linux_2.6_i386_v2.tar.gz" to extract the contents.
3. Open the Terminal application and type ~/KindleGen/kindlegen. Instructions on how to run KindleGen are displayed.
4. Conversion Example: To convert a file called book.html, go to the directory where the book is located, such as cd desktop, and type ~/KindleGen/kindlegen book.html. If the conversion was successful, a new file called book.mobi displays on the desktop.
5. Please note: It is recommended to follow these steps to run KindleGen. Double-clicking the KindleGen icon does not launch this program. Run the above commands without quotes.

Comment: Did you forget to type in the "~"?  Did you make the suggested directory KindleGen in your home directory?  Did you move the downloaded file to your new directory before unpacking it?  If you are on a 64 bit system, did you install the necessary 32 but libraries?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Finally i solved the problem and i took care of what you said but i experimented with the following: i used the sudo command to move the executable file into /usr/local/bin then restart kindle comic converter and to my extreme surprise it worked!! i am not sure what step made it work but sure enough that this part of the instructions " type ~/KindleGen/kindlegen" will trigger nothing but" No such file or directory" in terminal. Again thanks for interest.

Comment: I have searched the internet and for some reason amazon removed the download link for Kindlegen now they want you to download a pkg for Kindlegen preview. Question is would this also work as Kindlegen would? Does anybody know where on this internet I can find a link to download the .gz for Kindlegen?

Answer (score 5):

## Kindle Comic Converter (KCC) installation instructions for Linux

Before install KCC, you need to have *KindleGen* in your system.

1. Download the [KindleGen](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211) tar.gz to a folder such as Kindlegen in home directory (~/KindleGen).
2. Extract the contents of the file to '~/KindleGen'.

   - `$ cd ~/KindleGen`
   - `$ tar xvfz kindlegen_linux_2.6_i386_v2_9.tar.gz`
3. Move the file `kindlegen` to `/usr/local/bin/`

   - `$ mv ~/KindleGen/kindlegen /usr/local/bin/`

After you do that, download [Kindle Comic Converter](https://kcc.iosphe.re/Linux/) and install it.

Enjoy!

Comment: After following these steps, type kindlegen in the console to run KindleGen,

Comment: I have searched the internet and for some reason amazon removed the download link for Kindlegen now they want you to download a pkg for Kindlegen preview. Question is would this also work as Kindlegen would? Does anybody know where on this internet I can find a link to download the .gz for Kindlegen?

Comment: Try searching for `kindlegen_linux_2.6_i386_v2_9.tar.gz`. I've found it [here](https://github.com/zzet/fp-docker/blob/master/kindlegen_linux_2.6_i386_v2_9.tar.gz) (but it may disappear in future).